# Viewstate does not retain clientside changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, postback, viewstate

I have the following simple aspx code:

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("Label1").className = "clientAssignedClass";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Label" ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Change at server" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Change at client" OnClientClick="myFunction()" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

with the following cs code:

**WebForm1.aspx.cs**

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.CssClass = "serverAssignedClass";
        }
    }
}
```

When I click `Change at server (Button2)` button and then `Update` button, the class attribute is retained across postbacks, but when I click `Change at client (Button3)` and then `Update` button, the class attribute is not retained across postbacks (after `Update` postback any changes made at client are lost).

How can I maintain changes made at client (such as a class change made by Bootstrap, i.e. `active`) across postbacks ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I suppose it is doing what it is designed for. The view state on page is spitted into hidden field named `__VIEWSTATE`. As it at server side, it cannot take changes done on client side. It is a mechanism to carry back and forth information that you have on server. For more detailed introduction have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) article.

Your best bet to take css class set on client side is to put it into some field like `hidden field` so that it is posted back to server.

Answer (score 0):

ViewState is used to store the state of a page and its controls as set *on the server* so that state gets preserved between postbacks. It doesn't "know" about changes made to the page on the client.

ASP.NET webforms wants to manage the state of your page its way - everything is done on the server and changes to the state of the page are stored in ViewState.

If you've gotten used to more client-side code, as has become much more common, then working with webforms can be a little bit frustrating for reasons like this. You're trying to maintain your page state on the client, but the page contains server controls that post back to the server. The server then re-renders the page, destroying that client-side state, because it only knows about the state that it maintains.

If possible, your life will be easier if you don't try to mix to two. If you're stuck working on an existing webforms project, try to do everything on the server. If you're creating new content and you want to manage state on the client, avoid using server controls. Just use ASP.NET as an engine to render the initial view.

If you really, really wanted to do this, you could store values in cookies or local storage, and on page load check those values to see if you need to restore some CSS class when the page loads. You could even do something really weird like put details in hidden input, and then on the server side reflect that back somehow so that when the page reloads the client-side script knows what state to (re)set.

Comment: I don't know whether you're just learning or whether you're an experienced developer who's gotten stuck working on an existing webforms project. If you're the former, my recommendation would be to drop webforms and learn MVC. Webforms is dying. It's not useless to know because there's so much legacy code, but I can't see developing new applications with webforms. MVC is designed to be stateless so you won't have to deal with the server trying to manage the state of your view in between requests.

Comment: I ended up using `WebMethods` that are called with jQuery to update the server with the controls state, which then are stored in the web session. And when page/page section reloads, the state is restored from the web session. I'm just starting with ASP, and I looked at both MVC and Webforms, and it seems that Webforms are more straight forward to use. The project I do is heavy server side with a simple web interface, but with dynamically generated bootstrap controls.